# Unwind to a specific view controller without a segue

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, unwind-segue

When not using storyboards, how do you get the same functionality as an unwind segue? Say that I have a navigation controller with several view controllers in it, and I want to smoothly unwind back to a certain controller. How would you accomplish this?

Comment: You can use the `popToViewController` for that functionality. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller)

Comment: Is there a syntactical sugar way to do that without having to hold onto a bunch of controller references @MidhunMP? Like the unwind IBAction does for storyboards.

Comment: You can write an extension on navigation controller which will take the class name of the vc to which you have to unwind and you can find the object of that particular class from the viewcontroller array and pass that to the above mentioned method to unwind.

Comment: That's a good idea @MidhunMP. Better yet, is there a way to set an identifier on a controller and then fetch the controller from the nav stack by the identifier? That way if there's multiple of the same controller type, you can go to a specific one.

Comment: Yeah, you can check my answer below. I've added an identifier to go back to a specific view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an extension on the UINavigationController to achieve this. As per your comments, you want to set an identifier and go back using that particular identifier. For that purpose, you can write a simple protocol:

```
protocol Unwindable {
    var identifier: String { get set }
}
```

All your view controllers should confirm this protocol and set the identifier value. Implement the UINavigationController extension like:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func goBackToInstance(withIdentifier identifier: String) {
        let mapped = self.viewControllers.compactMap{ $0 as? Unwindable }
        for vc in mapped.reversed() {
            if (vc.identifier == identifier) {
                self.popToViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then go back using:

```
self.navigationController?.goBackToInstance(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier")
```